# Logical implementation of hierarchical networks

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on neural networks. I start with a big neural network. During some processing, that big neural network gets divided into smaller neural networks. Then again, those smaller neural networks have to be passed through the same processing step individually and will get divided into even smaller neural networks.

Following is the pictorial representation of what i have said above in words:

[image]

**First Step:** I have the above shown big neural network. I will do some processing on it which will divide it in smaller neural networks. ***I able to do this part***.

[image]

**Second Step:** The smaller networks resulted from the first big network have to be processed to further divide them into even smaller networks and it will result in the following thing.

[image]

**Third Step:** The same procedure will be applied to the smaller networks achieved in step-2 which will result in even smaller networks.

[image]

**PROBLEM:** I can subdivide the first bigger network into smaller networks. But even after thinking a lot, i am not able to come up with some kind of recursive algorithm to maintain this structure.

I just need some rough suggestion about the structure of my program to implement this problem.

**PS:** The number of layers are not fixed. The number of layers depend upon a termination criteria. I want to terminate the process when the network become so small that it can't be subdivided further.

**UPDATE:** I have a `class Layer` which takes control of everything thing. Then i have a `class Learner` which carries out the learning process (to subdivide network) for a given network. I have one more class which `class Network` which represents each individual `network`.

My current strategy is to make an object of Layer class i.e. `Layer layerObject` and then do the learning for that layer.

```
class Layer
{
    public:
        Learner* Learner;


};

class Learner
{
    public:
        Network* network;


};

class Network
{
    private:
        Node* currentSeed;


};
```

Comment: How do you model the network? How do you represent it?

Comment: @MariusBancila: i have edited my question, please have a look at `UPDATE` at the end. I am trying to put more information.

Comment: But what is a Network? A list, a tree, a graph? In your images, the original networks seem to remain the same. What happens to them after splitting. So you have node Network-1.1, but after splitting how does it look? In your example there is still a node with the same name there. What does it contain?

Comment: @MariusBancila: Network consists of 'Nodes'. Those nodes have inter-connections. During the leaning process, some connections are lost due to which some smaller networks are resulted. Smaller network also consists of the nodes.

Comment: does your first-split-method start on a special "starting node" or is your network very recurrent? cant you use the first-split-method on any sub-network?

Comment: the network (whether bigger or smaller) are processed through the same learning process and divided into even smaller network. I can do the processing manually by storing each network into a variable and then sending it for the learning process BUT i want to do it recursively.